# Filter Magento collection with nested "OR" "AND" filter

Tags: php

I am trying to determine how to filter a Magento collection from a flat table that would produce a WHERE clause with an AND that is followed by expression with a nested OR, which has nested ANDs, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_model_flat_table`
WHERE (`customer_id` = 123456) 
AND (
    ((`colA` = CONSTANT_A) AND (`colB` = $variableA))
    OR
    ((`colA` = CONSTANT_B) AND (`colB` = $variableB))
)
```

Short of doing this as two separate collections, loading and then merging them, I'm at a loss.

I'm trying to do this in a “Magento-friendly" way without resorting to:

```
$myCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',123456)
    ->getSelect()
    ->where(...put the nested logic in here...);
```

I've looked over the information at the following links, with no luck:

- http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-8.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826474/magento-addfieldtofilter-two-fields-match-as-or-not-and

What I have done at this juncture is to go with a SQL SELECT, rather than using Magento's Collections, to retrieve the IDs of resources I need. From there I am loading the individual objects as needed:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$dbReader = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('mymodule/mymodel');
$query = "SELECT mymodel_id FROM {$tableName} WHERE customer_id = :cId AND 
    ((colA = :eiType AND colB = :eiId) OR (colA = :mcType AND colB = :mcId)) 
    ORDER BY mymodel_id DESC";
$bindings = array(
    'cId'    => $customerId,
    'eiType' => $foreignKeyCodeA,
    'eiId'   => $foreignKeyA,
    'mcType' => $foreignKeyCodeB,
    'mcId'   => $foreignKeyB,
);
$myModelIds = $dbReader->fetchCol($query,$bindings);
```

This is not what I wanted to do, but it does cut down on making multiple Collection loads to get to the data I need.

I also want to note that in the database `colA` and `colB` form a unique index, so the 'OR' in the SELECT statement will not result in data collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$ids = array(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005);

Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSelect()
        ->where('main_table.entitry_id IN (?)', $ids);
```

it will filter collection  according to product ids which are coming in $ids array

Comment: This is the correct approach - use your direct SQL to fetch the ids as necessary and then use this to populate a product collection.

Comment: @karan-adhikari: You didn't answer the question I asked. You provided a way to get a product collection based on known IDs. For your example, there is even a much easier way:
`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',['in' => [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005]]);`

Answer (score 1):

Referencing how the core does this in `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Collection::addHasOptionsFilter()`, I come up with the following:

```
public function addFilters($foreignKeyCodeA, $foreignKeyA, $foreignKeyCodeB, $foreignKeyB)
{
    $adapter = $this->getConnection();
    $andWhereA = implode(' AND ', array(
        $adapter->quoteInto('(main_table.colA = ?)', $foreignKeyCodeA),
        $adapter->quoteInto('(main_table.colB = ?)', $foreignKeyA)
    ));
    $andWhereB = implode(' AND ', array(
        $adapter->quoteInto('(main_table.colA = ?)', $foreignKeyCodeB),
        $adapter->quoteInto('(main_table.colB = ?)', $foreignKeyB)
    ));
    $orWhere = implode(' OR ', array($andWhereA, $andWhereB));

    $this->getSelect()
        ->where($orWhere);

    return $this;
}
```

If you add the above in the collection class, then you can

```
$myCollection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',123456)
        ->addFilters($foreignKeyCodeA, $foreignKeyA, $foreignKeyCodeB, $foreignKeyB)
;
```

Comment: Beware: this approach eats memory. To get around it, retrieve only the IDs with `->getAllIds()`, which you can insert after `->addFilters()`.

Comment: Thanks @kiatng, I will modify a test copy of what I am working on to see if the nested arrays can work. I was thinking something like that would be the case, but could not puzzle it out. I also thing that what you would all need to be nested down in another AND. That is, your $orWhere would have to have an AND against $customerId. Thanks again for taking the to reply!